# Bounded Java Generics not compiling

Tags: java, generics

I am unable to get this to compile and I don't see the reason why. 
Ultimately I want to pass an Collection of objects who's class extends TClass into the generate method that takes a Collection of objects who's class extends TClass, 
This should work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public interface Generator<IT extends ITClass, T extends TClass> {

    IT generate(Collection<T> tClassCollection)
}

Generator<?, ? extends TClass> generator = generatorClass.newInstance();

Collection<? extends TClass> TClassCollection = ...
```

... `generator.generate(TClassCollection);`

I get this error

```
The method generate(Collection&lt;capture#8-of ? extends TClass>) in the type 
Generator&lt;capture#7-of ?,capture#8-of ? extends TClass> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection&lt;capture#9-of ? extends TClass>)
```

Comment: Does ITClass implement / extend from Collection<T> or Collection<? extends T> ?

Answer (score 1):

> This should work

No; it would open a loophole in the type system if it did. Consider:

```
class SpecialT extends TClass {}

class SpecialGenerator extends Generator<ITClass, SpecialT> {}

Generator<?, ? extends TClass> generator = SpecialGenerator.class.newInstance();
Collection<? extends TClass> TClassCollection = Arrays.asList(new TClass());
generator.generate(TClassCollection);
```

A `SpecialGenerator` can only work with a `Collection<SpecialT>`, but you are trying to pass a `Collection<TClass>`, which can contain instances of types other than `SpecialT`.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard in a generic declaration doesn't mean "any type"; it means "some particular unknown type."

So, if you have a `Generator<?, ? extends TClass>`, it doesn't mean you can pass its `generate()` method any `Collection` as long as it contains a subtype of `TClass`.

On the contrary, it means that you can't invoke its `generate()` method in a type-safe way, because you don't know the type of elements it is capable of accepting.