# Generics:Issues in Adding SubClass Objects in a Collection

Tags: java, generics

So I've been reading through the Generics tutorial offered by Oracle here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

And I've tried running my own example to make sure I understand how to use Generics. I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Generics {
    class NaturalNumber {
        private int i;

        public NaturalNumber(int i) { this.i = i; }
    }
    class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {
        public EvenNumber(int i) { 
            super(i);
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<? extends NaturalNumber> c = new ArrayList<>();
        c.add(new EvenNumber(2)); //this line produces a compile time error     
    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to add any object which is a subtype of NaturalNumber to the Collection c. I'm not sure why this doesn't work and reading through Oracle's tutorial hasn't enlightened me either.

Comment: Please add the compilation error message.  (I suspect it is actually nothing to do with generics ...)

Comment: Which specific part of the tutorial do you find confusing? I might be able to help, if I can find out which part you need help with.

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270851/bounded-java-generics-not-compiling?rq=1)

Comment: Are you compiling this with Java 7 or an older version?  An older version won't work.

Comment: @David Wallace: I'm using Java 6. But the suggestions below solved my issue.

Comment: I'm curious that you are using Java 6 and the diamond operator without data type actually works?

Comment: @ajavad If the line `Collection<NaturalNumber> c = new ArrayList<>();` from arshajii's solution compiles, then you are NOT using Java 6.

Comment: @Terry Li: The tutorial didn't specify the need for Java 7. It did tell me that I could use the diamond operator though.

Comment: @David Wallace: I changed it to `Collection<NaturalNumber> c = new ArrayList<NaturalNumber>();` and that worked for me. I plan on installing Java 7 at a later point in time. Thank you everyone for being so helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have `? extends NaturalNumber`, the parameter could be some *other* subclass of `NaturalNumber` that is in no way related to `EvenNumber`. For instance,

```
Collection<? extends NaturalNumber> c = new ArrayList<OtherNaturalNumber>();
```

is valid if `OtherNaturalNumber` extends `NaturalNumber`.

Consequently, you are not able to add an `EvenNumber` instance to the list. You can just use this declaration:

```
Collection<NaturalNumber> c = new ArrayList<>();
```

which will allow you to add any `NaturalNumber` instance (including an `EvenNumber`).

On another note, you probably meant to make those nested classes `static` (or don't nest them at all).

Comment: Also note the use of non-static inner classes, causing the error `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: @nickb Good point, he likely meant to make those classes `static`.

Answer (score 1):

First `Collection<? extends NaturalNumber>` should just be `Collection<NaturalNumber>`. Instances of `EvenNumber` (or any `NaturalNumber` or a subtype of `NaturalNumber`) can be put into the collection this way.

Essentially `Collection<? extends NaturalNumber>` says that the type of the type parameter to `Collection` extends `NaturalNumber`. So say that `class OddNumber extends NaturalNumber`, then the type of `Collection`'s type parameter could be `OddNumber` which `EvenNumber` cannot be safely cast to.

However there is another compiler error. To be used in the static context or `main(String[])` each of the inner classes `NaturalNumber` and `EvenNumber` need to have the modifier `static` placed on each class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've told the compiler that the `Collection`'s element type can be any type that `extends NaturalNumber`, but then you tried to *insert* an object into it. As far as the compiler knows, `c` is a `Collection<OddNumber>`, and you just added an `EvenNumber`!